# Homographies between several pictures for panorama stitching

Tags: matlab, image-processing, panoramas

I found out what the problem is. My solution was something that I took from the top of my head. When I sat down and did the calculations in details, I found two errors. There was one blunder and one rather subtle error.

The details are kind of involved, so suffice it to say that the correct operation is

```
T=[1 0 0; 0 1 0; 1-x(1) 1-y(1) 1]; 
H(:,:,i+1)=H(:,:,i)*T*H2*H1^-1*T^-1;
```

where x(1) and y(1) are the smallest non-zero coordinates in the transformed image.

If anyone is interested in the details, I can provide them,.

*ORIGINAL QUESTION*

*this is not really a programming question, but I don't know a better place to ask, since I haven't found any image processing Q&A places*

I have method in matlab [H1,H2]=findHomographies(I1,I2,size(I1)); that finds homographies H1 and H2, such that H1*I1 (applying H1 to I1) and H2*I2 overlap (more or less) in corresponding points of interest. It works well, as far as I can tell.

Now if I want to stitch together more than 2 images, I thought of keeping the first images as it is, apply H'=H2*H1^-1 to the second image, and then in order to find the homography H'' for the third image I first apply H' to the second and third image, run findHomographies on those and then find H1' and H2' for that pair of images. The third homography is then H''=H2'*H1'^-1*H'. The reason for why I do it like this, is that it should eliminate, or at least reduce error propagation.

However, in practice it doesn't seem to work well, as the following image shows

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAg9r.jpg

As you can see, the two first images are stitched together well, but between the second and third, there is a very noticable offset.

Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

The relevant code is given below

```
c=1
for i=1:c
    H(:,:,i)=eye(3);
end
corners=[1 1 imsize(2) imsize(2); 1 imsize(1) 1 imsize(1)];
for i=c:(n-1)
    cornersT=applyTrans(H(:,:,i)',corners);
    tform = projective2d(H(:,:,i));
    x=minmax(cornersT(1,:));
    y=minmax(cornersT(2,:));
    I1=imwarp(I(:,gi(i,s2),:), tform, 'OutputView', imref2d(imsize,[x(1) x(2)],[y(1) y(2)]));
    I2=imwarp(I(:,gi(i+1,s2),:), tform, 'OutputView', imref2d(imsize,[x(1) x(2)],[y(1) y(2)]));    
    [H1,H2]=findHomographies(I1,I2,size(I1));
    H(:,:,i+1)=H2*H1^-1*H(:,:,i);
end
corners=[1 1 imsize(2) imsize(2); 1 imsize(1) 1 imsize(1)];
cornersT=applyTrans(H(:,:,1)',corners);
for i=2:n
    cornersT=[cornersT applyTrans(H(:,:,i)',corners)];
end
x=minmax(cornersT(1,:));
y=minmax(cornersT(2,:));
tform = projective2d(H(:,:,1));
IRect=imwarp(I(:,gi(1,s2),:), tform, 'OutputView', imref2d(imsize,[x(1) x(2)],[y(1) y(2)]));
for i=2:n
    tform = projective2d(H(:,:,i));
    IRect2 = imwarp(I(:,gi(i,s2),:), tform, 'OutputView', imref2d(imsize,[x(1) x(2)],[y(1) y(2)]));
    IRect=imagestitch(IRect,IRect2);
end
figure; imshow(IRect);
```

Comment: This would probably be more suited to http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you. I will keep that in mind the next time I ask a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to correct the images for radial distortion. I recommend taking a very close look at Rick Szeliski's book Computer Vision for a detailed treatment of this subject.

Comment: Also check out Rick's tutorial paper online here: http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/70092/tr-2004-92.pdf

Comment: Thank you. That could indeed have been the problem, but in this case it was not :)